# Android Dialog out of dialog click

Tags: android, dialog

I made a custom dialog (extends Dialog) and then make the object in Activity Sample.class

Then if I click one button in the Activity and the custom dialog shows up.

Here, the problem is, since the custom dialog contains the EditText, the soft keyboard is needed and it shows up, but if I click(tab) the screen outside of the dialog, the "cancel" listener is called so that the dialog is disappeared. However, what I want to implement is when I click the screen outside of the dialog, only just keyboard disappearing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) on the dialog instance. This will stop dismissing the dialog. But I am not sure the soft keypad will go away with this.

Comment: Thanks, it really worked well, however, the soft keypad did not go away. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sure, I will. Anyway what do you mean by removing the focus from the edit text?

Comment: You need to manually remove the soft key pad by listening to the window focus change for the dialog box. InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

use this,
              `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: I think you've got a mistake. the parameter would be 'false', anyway thank you